# private interface AND multiple implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

There is a simple Object-C code snippet I got from a iOS project:

```
@interface store (private)

@end

@implementation store (private)

@end

@implementation store
```

My questions are:

1. What does `(private)` mean in the code, private interface & implementation?
2. What does the last line `@implementation store` mean? An empty public implementation? Without `@end`?
3. Since there are two `@implementation store` in above code, does that mean objective-c support multiple implementation for a single interface?

Answer (score 1):

1. `What does (private) mean in the code, private interface & implementation?` - `(private)` means that you are decalring/implementing an objective-c [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). In this case `private` is just a name. It wouldn't make difference if it was `store (myPrivateMethods)`
2. `What does the last line @implementation store mean? An empty public implementation? Without @end?` - `@implementation store` is the actual implementation part of the class `store`. Not sure what happens if an `@end` is missing.
3. `Since there are two @implementation store in above code, does that mean objective-c support multiple implementation for a single interface?` - Actually there aren't 2 implementations of `store`. There is one implementation of the class `store` and one implementation of a category of that class - `store (private)`.

Answer (score 0):

`private` means nothing in Objective-C, you call it `peanuts` if you want. It's really a label to differentiate categories if you have multiple, but it's value is arbitrary. It just has to mean something to you as a developer.

The `@implementation store` line marks the beginning of the implementation for the class defined by `@interface store` (i.e. no category), which is probably declared in a '.h' file. It's the fact that the interface is in the '.h' that makes it public (because other classes can import the `.h` file and therefore see the declaration of properties, methods, etc...).

It doesn't support multiple implementations, they are additive. Of course, then you have the question of implementing the same method in both. This is strongly discouraged by Apple. Here's the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

> **Avoid Category Method Name Clashes**
>
> Because the methods declared in a category are added to an existing class, you need to be very careful about method names.
>
> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to be an issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa or Cocoa Touch classes.

Answer (score 0):

1. That's an [objective-c category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html), allowing you to add code to an existing class.  The name in parens is arbitrary.
2. That's an empty implementation, but I'm surprised it compiles without an `@end`.  Trying it xcode with default compiler settings, I get an error.  If only for clarity, it ought to have an `@end`.
3. The first implementation is an add-on to the first.  You can use it to break big classes into separate modules, to make portions of an interface available to some and not to others, or -- most usefully and commonly -- add methods to SDK classes.